# Remove Product SKU from order details in WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications, sku

I've been trying to remove the product SKU located after the product title in WooCommerce email notifications.

I have tried the following:

```
function sv_remove_product_page_skus( $enabled ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_product() ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $enabled;
}
add_filter( 'wc_product_sku_enabled', 'sv_remove_product_page_skus' );
```

But didn't work, the product SKU remains after the product title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove product SKU from email notifications, simply use the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_args', 'customize_email_order_items_args', 20 );
function customize_email_order_items_args( $items_args ) {
    $items_args['show_sku'] = false;

    return $items_args;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.